# python multiprocessor how to stop all threads when on one of them find the result?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am trying to run my code in parallel using the python "from multiprocessing import Process, Value" model.However, I am creating a shared variable and using it as flag, so if one process find the result it will set the flag value to 1 and exit.Other processes should exit when the flag value is changed but for some reason the flag value did not change for these processes. this is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
gflag= Value('i',0)#this is the global flag shared between process
gflag=0
while True:                                                                                                                                                                      
    if not piece:                                                                                                                                                                  
        break                                                                                                                                                                      

    list1= piece.splitlines()                                                                                                                                                         

    p = Process(target=Dowork, args=(gflag,inValue,list1,var1,))                                                                                                                     

    p.start()                                                                                                                                                                      
    if(gflag==1):                                                                                                                                                                  
            exit()                                                                                                                                                                 

    piece = f.read(10000)

def doWork(gflag,inputvalue,diclist,var1):
    for p in diclist:
        calResult= doSomeCal(p,var1)
        if( calResult == inputvalue):
            gflag=1
            exit()

    if(gflag==1):
        print"exit now"
        exit()
```

Question is how to stop all the threads when on of them find the result?

Comment: As a side note, instead of creating a new process for every 10k of data, it might be better to use a `Pool`, and just create a new job for each 10k, running on the pool.

Comment: Also, this code can't possibly work as written, because you're testing `if not piece` before ever assigning anything to it. Presumably your real code does something different—but you might want to consider rewriting it as a `for` loop, e.g., `for piece in iter(lambda: f.read(10000), ''):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your attempted solution is that, because you assign to `gflag` within `doWork`, it's a local variable, not a global. To fix that, you need to add `global gflag` at the start of the function.

But even if you fixed that, it wouldn't solve your problem. When you write `gflag=1`, that doesn't update the shared value stored in `gflag`, it just rebinds the name `gflag` to the local int `1`. You want to use `gflag.value`. (Note that once you fix this, the previous problem goes away… but it's still often better to use the `global` declaration for human readers, even when the compiler doesn't need it.)

And finally, `doWork` doesn't actually check the flag until after it's finished doing all the work, so the flag doesn't help you to exit the child processes earlier. You probably want to put that `if` statement inside the `for` loop, so it checks the flag once per element, instead of only once at the end.

Comment: thank you I implement you instruction and it work like a charm now